# understanding different nested function call

Tags: javascript

I know there are plenty of good answers related to calling nested functions but my question happens to be different.

Suppose we have a code like this

```
function a() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    alert(c++);
  }
  return b;
}
var d = a();
d();
```

Here we did `return b` and then

```
 var d = a();
    d();
```

to call it i.e it only runs when we do  `d();` but in an almost identical code

```
function a() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    alert(c++);
  }
  return b();
}

var d = a();
```

Where we did  `return b();`, we can call it directly by `var d = a();` and do not need to call `d();`, Why is that so? I know the difference in return b and return b() is making the difference but still can someone please explain why , **we can call it directly by `var d = a();` and do not need to call `d();?**

Comment: The first `a()` returns a function, which is callable. The second `a()` returns `undefined`, which is not callable.

Comment: `return b` means it rerurn value instead of call function and `return b()` means its call a function no need to call after another time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, what's happening is that by adding parentheses with `var d = a();` you're actually calling function `a`. When running your code

```
function a() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    alert(c++);
  }
  return b();
}

var d = a();
d();
```

it gives an error, and what happened is that d is not a function, when you assign `a()` to `var d` you're assigning the **result** of a(), which in `function a`, it will return the result of a, because `return b()`is actually calling `function b` which returns the **result** of `function b`, so in turn, `var d` is actually equal to 0 when the code is run. If you want to assign the actual function `a` to the variable `d`, just remove the parentheses like this

```
function a() {
  var c = 0;
  function b() {
    alert(c++);
  }
  return b;
}

var d = a; <-------
d();
```

And it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

> we can call it directly by var d = a(); and do not need to call `d();?

You not just "do not need to call"  - you can not call "d();"

(If the return value of function b is not a function)

But why?

Because you assigned the return value of function a to your variable d. 
The return value of "a" (unfortunately) is the return value of the function "b".

Now if the return value of function "b" is not a function (and I guess its not) then you will have "d" assigned to an object or an int or essentially everything else than a function wich means "d();" would be an invalid operation.

Answer (score 0):

When you return "b" you return the function reference.

When you return "b()" you call the function and return the result.

```
You can easy map this to the ajax:
function onSuccess() {
...
}
$.ajax(url, onSuccess);
```

You pass the reference to the function which will be called after the ajax is finnished.

But this:

```
$.ajax(url, onSuccess());
```

You call onSuccess immediately and pass the result to the function.

Comment: Why would you add jquery functions? I think this makes it more complicated to understand your answer